# Make a factory wait for a button click to load

Tags: angularjs

```js
.controller("Canned", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray","Data", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $ionicModal, Data) {
    $scope.deleteItem = function(cannedLst) {
    $scope.cannedLsts.$remove(cannedLst); 
    };
    
    var cannedRef = new Firebase("https://pricemonitoringsys.firebaseio.com/dti")
    $scope.cannedGoods = $firebaseArray(cannedRef);
    var query = cannedRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo("canned");
    $scope.cannedLsts = $firebaseArray(query);
  }
])
```

i want to pass my data to this controller when i hit the button but on load it triggers the factory and my Controller thats why i always end up fetching nothing since my factory contains nothing yet i want it to trigger when i click the button someone please help me this is for my thesis and i need to submit this on Monday

```js
.factory('Data', function(){
  return { searchData: ''};  
})

.controller('CompareModal', function($scope, $ionicModal, Data, $firebaseArray) {
  $scope.compareMe = function(Data) {
    console.log(Data)
    Data.searchData = Data;
    $scope.modal.show();
  }
})

.controller("Compare", ["$scope", "$firebaseArray","Data", function($scope,$firebaseArray,Data) {

    var x = angular.copy(Data.searchData);
    console.log(x)

    var cannedRef = new Firebase("https://pricemonitoringsys.firebaseio.com/store1")

    $scope.cannedGoods = $firebaseArray(cannedRef);

    var query = cannedRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(x);

    $scope.filteredMessages = $firebaseArray(query);
  }
])
```

```html
<ion-item class="col item-text-wrap" ng-controller="CompareModal">
            <button class="button button-balanced button-small" ng-model="Data.searchData" ng-click="compareMe(Data.searchData = cannedLst.name)">₱ {{cannedLst.price}}</button>
        </ion-item>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? The compare controller calls your factory straight away, so the behaviour you describe is to be expected?!

Comment: @mindparse no luck yet how do i do this? i wanna assign the cannedLst.name to Data.searchData how do i do this?

Comment: this code works if i assign the Data.searchData manually so i am thinking there must be something wrong with how i pass the data @mindparse

Comment: It's hard to follow your code, where and when is cannedLst assigned?

Comment: @mindparse when i hit the button sir

Comment: <button class="button button-balanced button-small" ng-model="Data.searchData" ng-click="compareMe(Data.searchData = cannedLst.name)">₱ {{cannedLst.price}}</button>

Comment: Yes I see that, but where does cannedLst come from? You obviously have it as an object somewhere since you are using the price property for the content of the button. Since the buttons scope is bound to your CompareModal controller, I expected to see cannedLst as a variable in there but I don't. Is there more code you can post?

Comment: Is the button part of an ng-repeat using the cannedGoods?

Comment: @mindparse id email the code to you if its okay

Comment: @mindparse the cannedLst comes from a controller wait ill edit my post

Comment: edited it @mindparse